# Parallelizing this nested loop in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to cut the execution time of my code (it takes way too long) and can't figure how to use/implement multiprocessing in it!

(Python 3.9)

The code that I need to run in a parallel environment:
(Im leaving out dataframe processing out of the equation below)

```
def getJson(url):
 match_page = requests.get(url)
 match_json = match_page.text
 match_json = json.loads(match_json) 
 return match_json


def waitforEvent (id): 
  event =   getJson(json_page)
  series_list = event['event']['series']
  for s in series_list:
   sId = str(s['id'])
   series_page = series_api + sId
   series_json =   getJson(series_page)
   for match in series_json['series']['matches']:
     matchDetailsJson =   getJson(match_api+str(match['id']))
```

Tried to somehow optimize json loading time using orjson & ujon, as well as using request sessions.

Comment: Presumably all the time will be spent waiting for the network, threading or asyncio would likely work fine in this case.  Note that you will likely start hitting usage limits on a server if you go too fast, and you might want to look at caching results so you're not waiting for the network too much

Comment: @SamMason I did time the amount of time the requests take and fortunately requests aren't the bottleneck, the loop is apparently.

Comment: that's very unusual in my experience!  is the web server local to you  (e.g. in the same data-centre) or something?  how do you distinguish between "the loop" and the requests you're doing inside it?

Comment: If you could modify your question to include timings of some of the requests you're doing, then the sizes of some of the responses and the time it takes to parse them

Comment: And also when the dataframe processing takes place. I'm guessing it's in the `for` loop?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes, each series is exported as excel file so it has to be in the loop!

Comment: trying to do network things along with writing out files all in one loop sounds like the wrong approach.  also Excel files are a terrible format and you almost certainly want to persist intermediate results some other way.  If you've written code to create files then you likely need more code to deal with the many files you're creating, Excel just makes things like this worse.  the first step of most data science tasks is getting data out of Excel files and into a sane storage format

Comment: I'd suggest trying to use an intermediate data structure to store the results you get from the server.  it would likely also help to find something that's easier to interact with programmatically like a database (the `sqlite3` module is good) or just write the raw response to (text) files (i.e. before `load`ing).  that way you can just load everything back into memory rather than doing all the network requests all over again

Comment: Must use Excel in this case sadly, the entire script takes 6-10 seconds to execute, 1-2 of it is exporting the Excel.. Its the loop.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound condescending, but it would be easier to tell you how to speed it up if you show us the part that needs speeding up. In other words, a [mre].

Comment: @Alazin just because some output needs to be Excel doesn't mean it's not helpful to store intermediate state in a form that's more amenable to computation.  I'm interpreting the up-votes on my comments as other people agreeing with my experience.  That said, if you don't provide more detail it's difficult to say anything more specific and the question is liable to get closed because of this.